# as3 - displaying "0" when seconds are under "10"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, zero, seconds

I'm actually displaying the current time (including seconds) on an application I'm working on (Adobe Flash with AS3). I've made it to be able to display the date, hours, minutes and seconds, however, I noticed, that my seconds under the value "10" are displayed without any zero. Example: 8:48:5 (zero missing). I hope someone of you can help me. Thanks in advance :)

var my_date:Date;

```
var my_timer:Timer=new Timer(1000);
my_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
my_timer.start();

function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
my_date = new Date();
tag.text = "" +my_date.date+"."+my_date.month+"."+my_date.fullYear+"  "+my_date.hours+":"+my_date.minutes+":"+my_date.seconds;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to comment of user @akmozo you can use this:

`(my_date.seconds < 10 ? "0" + my_date.seconds : my_date.seconds);`

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. It displays: AS3 #1067: Implict Coercion of a number into string

Comment: @SteffPoint oh, I'm sorry, I have confused this with javascript.

Comment: There's no need to apologize :)

Comment: @SteffPoint `(condition) ? if : else` works in javascript, but you can replace it with if else.. something like `if (seconds < 10) {my_date.seconds = ...} else {...}` before `tag.text`

Comment: I've already tried it like this. The problem is that "seconds" is a not definied property. I',m not sure if I have to open some kind of Variable for it

Comment: You should write : `(my_date.seconds < 10 ? "0" + my_date.seconds : my_date.seconds);` ...

Comment: @SteffPoint You are welcome. You can select Segio's answer as accepted as it was what you are looking for.

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Please update your answer to put the 2nd parenthesis at the good position.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. U saved me a lot of experimenting and googling time :)